# Using underscore _.delay, how do I stop future execution and provide user status

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I need to process an array of input slowly, making asych calls for each element without hitting a rate limit on a server.  I can do most of what I want with [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) `_.delay()`, but how do I (a) cancel the delayed execution if the user decides to bail, and (b) show status that includes the current index of the array.

Here's what I have so far...

```
function processArray(array) {
    var processElement = function(element) {
        return doAsynch(element);  // asynch task returning a promise
    };

    _.each(array, function(element, index) {
        _.delay(processElement, index * 1000, element);
    });
}

function userDecidesToCancel() {
    // stuck here
}
```

If the user decides to cancel, say just before we get to element N, I'm happy to let `doAsynch(N-1)` complete, but I don't want to start work for anything further (for N >= 1).  Is there a way?

Also, regarding status, I can't figure out how to elegantly present that we finished item N of total, i.e. I'd like to say ...

```
    _.each(array, function(element, index) {
        _.delay(processElement, index * 1000, element).then(function(result) {
            // how can I get the result here? I'd like to log status
            console.log("just did " + index + " " + result);
        });
    });
```

I can put part of that log message in the `processElement` function (the part that logs the result), but I also need the index relative to the array length so I can show percent progress.  I think knowledge of that index properly belongs in the `_.each` loop, not passed to the `processElement` function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd encourage you to check out a library of mine, Task Runner- http://bvaughn.github.io/task-runner/. It has built-in support for pausing and resuming asynchronous chains of operation, as well for reporting the progress of such chains. I know it's not an Underscore answer, which is why I'm leaving it as a comment instead of an answer, but I think you might dig it. (And I'd love to hear your thoughts about the library, either way!)

Comment: `_.delay` does not support cancellation. And notice that it doesn't return a promise, no idea where you got that `.then()` from?

Comment: @brianvaughn - thanks so much.  Just skimmed it and it looks really well thought out.  Looks like a little learning curve, but I might try it out.

Comment: @Bergi - Thanks.  The code in that second block was trying to articulate what I want, not what I think I have.

Comment: If you do, please let me know and I'll be glad to help or answer any questions! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscores' [_.delay](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L758) function just wraps the original `setTimeout`.
So you can collect all of the timeouts and then cancel them with `clearTimeout`:

```
var cancels = _.map(array, function(element, index) {
  return _.delay(processElement, index * 1000, element);
});

function cancel() {
  // you can also track the current element from processElement and cancel 
  // only the timeouts that follow that one, but it might be an overkill.
  _.each(cancels, function(cancel) {
    clearTimeout(cancel);
  });
}
```

Unfortunately with the current implementation I dont see a way to get the promise from `processElement`.

Comment: works, thanks.  i guess I'm stuck passing the index all the way into the delayed function in order to handle status.